# Как добавить QTabBar на QMainWindow?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qtabwidget

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У каждого браузера вкладки находятся на заголовке окна *Windows*, я хочу сделать то же самое в *PyQt5*, т.е. добавлять вкладки не в `QTabWidget`, а в заголовок окна.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста пример, который у вас есть.

Comment: У меня нет примера(кода)... Поэтому и спрашиваю, чтобы иметь хоть какое-то представление

Comment: @IReXZ у меня как-то была такая проблема. Я просто удалил рамку окна и сделал свою. На новую рамку можно добавить все что угодно

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTabBar, QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, \
    QTabWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow


class TabBar(QTabBar):
    def tabSizeHint(self, index):
        size = QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index)
        w = int(self.width()/self.count())
        return QSize(w, size.height())


class Container(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(Container, self).__init__()

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)

        self.button = QPushButton(text)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.button)


class CustomWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.tabNum = 3
        self.button = QPushButton("Add tab")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setTabBar(TabBar())
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabs.setMovable(True)
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tabs.setElideMode(Qt.ElideRight)
        self.tabs.setUsesScrollButtons(True)
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.closeTab)

        self.tabs.addTab(Container("Very big titleeeeeeeeee"),
                         "Very big titleeeeeeeeeeee")
        self.tabs.addTab(Container("Tab 1"), "Tab 1")
        self.tabs.addTab(Container("Tab 2"), "Tab 2")

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)
        vbox.addWidget(self.tabs)

    def closeTab(self, index):
        tab = self.tabs.widget(index)
        tab.deleteLater()
        self.tabs.removeTab(index)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        text = f'Tab {self.tabNum}'
        self.tabs.addTab(Container(text), text)
        self.tabNum += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    app.setStyleSheet("""
        QTabBar::tab:selected {
            background: gray;
            color: white;
        }
    """)
    window = CustomWidget() 
    window.resize(600, 600)
    window.show()                         
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но мне надо чтобы вкладки были как у браузера... на заголовке окна

Comment: @IReXZ  вы спросили: "Как добавить QTabBar на QMainWindow", я ответил. Попытайтесь сделать что-то самостоятельно. Если будет не получаться, зададите новый вопрос и приложите свой пример.

Comment: Всё перепробовал... Всё равно никак...

Comment: @IReXZ `Во-первых`, вы должны четко  формулировать вопрос, что вы хотите сделать.  `Во-вторых`, покажите что вы пробовали.

Comment: я немного дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Если заморочиться, то один из вариантов интерфейса г-браузера (`г`, потому что garage-version) представлен ниже (Код готов к употреблению, надо только добавить импорты):

```
# Класс верхней полоски, при помощи которой можно таскать все окно и на которой 
# располагаются все наши табы
class CaptionBelt(QFrame):

    # window - ссылка на объект окна, которое надо таскать
    def __init__(self, window, parent=None):
        QFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.Panel)
        self.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.window = window
        self.pos = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.pos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pos:
            d = event.pos() - self.pos
            self.window.move( self.window.pos() + d)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.pos = None

# Основной интерфейс приложения
class Ui_Browser(object):
    def setupUi(self, Browser):
        if Browser.objectName():
            Browser.setObjectName(u"Browser")
        Browser.resize(457, 293)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(Browser)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.frame = CaptionBelt(Browser, self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setObjectName(u"frame")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QHBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.layoutTabs = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layoutTabs.setObjectName(u"layoutTabs")
        self.layoutTabs.setSpacing(0)

        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.layoutTabs)

        # Добавление нового таба
        self.toolButtonNewTab = QToolButton(self.frame)
        self.toolButtonNewTab.setObjectName(u"toolButtonNewTab")

        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.toolButtonNewTab)

        self.horizontalSpacer = QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(self.horizontalSpacer)

        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_5")

        # Минимизировать приложение
        self.toolButton = QToolButton(self.frame)
        self.toolButton.setObjectName(u"toolButton")

        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.toolButton)

        # Развернуть/свернуть приложение
        self.toolButton_2 = QToolButton(self.frame)    
        self.toolButton_2.setObjectName(u"toolButton_2")

        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.toolButton_2)

        # Закрыть приложение
        self.toolButton_3 = QToolButton(self.frame)
        self.toolButton_3.setObjectName(u"toolButton_3")

        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.toolButton_3)

        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)

        self.widget_2 = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget_2.setObjectName(u"widget_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QHBoxLayout(self.widget_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_3")
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self.widget_2)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(u"lineEdit")

        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.widget_2)

        self.widget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setObjectName(u"widget")
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.widget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.widget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.widget)

        Browser.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(Browser)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        Browser.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(Browser)

        self.toolButton.clicked.connect(Browser.showMinimized)
        self.toolButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda : Browser.showNormal() if Browser.isMaximized() else Browser.showMaximized())
        self.toolButton_3.clicked.connect(Browser.close)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Browser)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Browser):
        Browser.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Browser", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.toolButtonNewTab.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Browser", u"+", None))
        self.toolButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Browser", u"_", None))
        self.toolButton_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Browser", u"O", None))
        self.toolButton_3.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Browser", u"X", None))
    # retranslateUi

# Класс таба. Дизайн выглядит так |<метка>(Х)|
class Tab(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        QFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())

        self.layout().setSpacing(0)
        self.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.Panel)

        self.label = QLabel(text)
        self.closeButton = QToolButton()
        self.closeButton.setText("x")

        self.layout().addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.closeButton)

        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.__closeTab)

    def __closeTab(self):
        self.setParent(None)
        self.close()
        self.deleteLater()

# Главное окно нашего г-браузера
class Browser(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Browser()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Убираем скучную и не интересную стандартную верхнюю полосу
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        # Добавляем новую  вкладку
        self.ui.toolButtonNewTab.clicked.connect(self.__newTab)
        self.tab_num = 1

    def __newTab(self):
        self.ui.layoutTabs.addWidget(Tab(f"Закладка {self.tab_num}"))
        self.tab_num += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Browser()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: хех, хорошая попытка, я так тоже делал, из-за этого приходиться писать множество уже готовых методов самому)
+ там свои проблемы возникают...
Мне кажется, что это нужно напрямую работать с оконным менеджером
Но всё равно спасябки)

Comment: @IReXZ позябки)